# Deleting specific blob version in Azure

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am trying to delete a specific blob version in Azure with versioning and soft delete enabled. The version I am trying to delete is the current version. For this I make a DELETE request and provide the versionid query param. However when I do this I get the following error in the reply (http status 403):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
   <Code>OperationNotAllowedOnRootBlob</Code>
   <Message>The specified operation is not allowed on root blob. RequestId:xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxx Time:2024-01-12T22:14:34.4251783Z</Message>
</Error>
```

However if I make 2 DELETE requests: 1st WITHOUT specifying the versionid query param the operation succeeds, the blob will not have a current version anymore, but if I inspect the blob using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer the blob still has an Active Status. I then make a 2nd DELETE request this time specifying the versionid query param and this operation succeeds and the status of the blob moves in Deleted. It will eventually be permanently deleted after 1 day.

If I make only 1 DELETE request WITHOUT specifying versionid the only change is that the blob will not have a current version but its status will remain active and will not be deleted after 1 day. So I must move the status in Deleted to make sure the blob will be actually deleted by making the 2nd DELETE request with versionid.

Sometimes even this way of deleting doesn't succeed. Even though I am not getting any errors I still have active blobs (for which I made 2 successful DELETE requests) in my container. I can observe this behaviour also in Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer: sometimes I right click a blob without a current version that is in Active state, the operation succeeds, but the blob is not moved in Deleted. If I right click Delete a second time then the blob will move in Deleted.

Is this the correct way of deleting (moving status in Deleted) a specific version of a blob in Azure by making 2 DELETE requests or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> The specified operation is not allowed on root blob.
> RequestId:xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxx Time:2024-01-12T22:14:34.4251783Z

The above error occurs when you try to delete the current version of a blob.

> Deleting a specific blob version in Azure

In Azure blob storage, you can able to delete the previous version with a version ID using the Azure REST API.

> Sometimes, even this way of deleting doesn't succeed. Even though I am not getting any errors, I still have active blobs (for which I made 2 successful DELETE requests) in my bucket. I can observe this behavior also in Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer: sometimes, when I right-click a blob without a current version that is in an Active state, the operation succeeds, but the blob is not moved to Deleted. If I right-click Delete a second time, then the blob will move to Deleted.

If blob soft delete is also enabled for the storage account, the version is maintained in the system until the soft delete retention period elapses (like one day or 7 days).

You can disable soft delete for containers and blobs.

**Portal:**

[image]

After disabling soft delete for blobs and containers, if you delete the current version of a blob, you won't be able to see the active status in Storage Explorer.

**Reference:**

1. [Blob versioning - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/versioning-overview#versioning-on-delete-operations)
2. [Azure Storage Explorer blob versioning guide | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-explorer-blob-versioning)

Comment: I tried the same on a storage account without soft delete and the behaviour is the same, except the blob is removed immediately, not moved into a Deleted status. Making a single DELETE request with versionid param on the initial current version returns the error OperationNotAllowedOnRootBlob The documentation says "To delete a specific version of a blob, provide the ID for that version on the delete operation." so the DELETE request with versionid on the current version should succeed.. Is the behaviour with 2 DELETE requests an undocumented feature of Azure?

Comment: To delete the current version you don't need to add `versionId` it will take automatically, for deleting the previous version the version ID is needed.